# How to make an java application compatible with multiple java version

Tags: java, version-control, compatibility

I am using some Enterprise application which requires different java version.

One application requires java 1.6 update 15 but another application requires java 1.7 update 55.

In my system I cannot use both the application simultaneously.I have to switch between the java versions in control panel frequently in order to access both.

So how could I access both the application without these issues.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Java 1.7 update 55 for both applications. Applications compiled with JDK 1.6 are supported by JRE 7 due backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

In the command line to start the applications, just point to the exact location of the different Java versions installed on your machine.
Something like this, depending of the OS and installation paths on your machine

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_15\bin\java.exe oneApplication
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\java.exe anotherApplication
```